# When is the kernel buffer cache empty for Disk I/O?

Tags: c, linux, io

When is the kernel buffer cache empty? This does not seem to be LINE Buffering. If I write () a string without a newline character, it is immediately output to the file.

In addition, does the input and output buffers of the socket file also use the kernel buffer cache like Disk I / O? Also, does the input and output buffers of the kernel space used for read() and write() exist for each open file (fd)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd = open("text", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);

    write(fd, "message", strlen("message"));

    // I can check the string in the file without fsync(fd).
    sleep(30);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the contents are reaching the disk? If you are simply reading the contents of the file from another process like `cat`, it could also be reading from the kernel buffer.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Oh! I never thought of it. Thank you. If so, the current file may be in a state that is not actually written and only buffered in kernel space.

Comment: @gradientw: That's why stuff like `sync`/`fsync` are generally discouraged for anything without strict transactional integrity rules. The `write` itself is enough to make the file work "as if" the write has completed for all practical purposes save power failure or the kernel itself crashing, since barring extreme measures, everyone else is reading the file via the same kernel buffering layer. Kernel crashes are much less common nowadays, and people rarely feel the need to protect against power failure, so `fsync` and company needlessly slow your program to achieve a very small benefit.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thank you. However, in the case of a socket, if I write () to a socket descriptor, I can read it immediately. Is this the way kernel buffering works? In other words, should I study Disk I / O and Socket I / O separately?

Answer (score 0):

> When is page cache bypassed?

Page cache shall be bypassed using direct I/O, provided that

- opened with O_DIRECT flag
- certain offset/address alignment constraint is met
- no extending writes performed

See [this link](https://lwn.net/Articles/348739/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I can set the input and output buffers according to fd through the setvbuf function. If so, is the page cache area also clearly seperated between the input and output parts?

Comment: As described, I / O buffers on disk I / O seem to use one space, called kernel buffer cache, without distinction between input and output. Is this right?

Comment: `man setvbuf(3)` shows the manual entry is in section 3, typical section for libc, also the required header is <stdio.h>, which means its libc not syscall. I think you're confusing libc buffer with page cache. By default libc io is line-buffered on the foreground, fully-buffered on the background, meaning on the background chars are only put onto libc internal buffer instead of commited to os via write(2). The libc function setvbuf is provided to modify that behavour. Page cache is an operationg system thing.

Comment: Thank you. I found that disk file I / O uses page cache rather than I / O buffers. The reason I was confused is socket file I / O. I found that disk file I / O and socket file I / O have different internal operations, and socket files have I / O buffers, unlike disk file I / O. I'm wondering if the socket file's I / O buffer is the same as the TCP / UDP send/receive buffer, or if there is a separate I / O buffer. Can you answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming Linux for the answers below)

> When is the kernel buffer cache empty?

You would need more context for this to be answerable. Additionally as you seem to be making files in a filesystem I'll refer to the kernel cache being used as the page cache, see the ["What is the major difference between the buffer cache and the page cache?"](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-major-difference-between-the-buffer-cache-and-the-page-cache-Why-were-they-separate-entities-in-older-kernels-Why-were-they-merged-later-on) quora question for the difference. For example, a write can be in the kernel page cache but not have made its way to do disk (i.e. dirty) or it can be in BOTH the page cache AND on disk (i.e. it got written out but the kernel is choosing to hold on to it in RAM). Do you mean "made clean" or do you mean "entirely discarded from the page cache"? Or do you mean "when is the I/O done visible to other programs working on the same file"?

> This does not seem to be LINE Buffering

At the *C library level* there's a difference between [I/O done on streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-on-Streams.html#I_002fO-on-Streams) (which can be line buffered) and [low-level I/O done on file descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-I_002fO.html#Low_002dLevel-I_002fO). Your example is using file descriptors so there would [never be line buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51483636/2732969). Further, C library buffering is orthogonal to kernel buffering.

> does the input and output buffers of the socket file also use the kernel buffer cache like Disk I / O?

Sockets don't use the page cache as they aren't block or file backed. However, [socket I/O IS buffered using `sk_buff` in the kernel](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1312).

> Also, does the input and output buffers of the kernel space used for read() and write() exist for each open file (fd)?

Sorry, I don't understand the question. The page cache is shared for files/block devices so multiple file descriptors to the same file will be serviced by the same entries in the page cache (assuming they are requesting identical offsets).

(`ETOOMANYQUESTIONS`! @andoryu please can you limit one question per post? It's tough going for someone trying to answer otherwise. Thanks!)